# ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 58 in class file

Tags: java, tomcat, java-6

I am working on a web application using servlet and jsp in windows OS, using Java 1.6.0_07 and tomcat 6.0.45 version. By taking the generated class files from my system and try to run it in solaris server which installed with Java 1.6 and tomcat 6.0 version it is throwing fallowing exception

```
May 20, 2016 1:41:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet IpsmscRamtIsdMsgStatisticsServlet
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 58 in class file com/abc/servlet/operator/ramt/statistics/isdstats/IpsmscRamtIsdMsgStatisticsServlet
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1815)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:869)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1322)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1201)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1034)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:757)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:495)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:199)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:282)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:767)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:697)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:889)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

When I was googled for the same, some of them told like "this might happen because java files are corrupted" but same files working fine in my system and in linux system (which have Java 1.6 and tomcat 6.0 version)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As error mentioned JRE on destination machine Solaris is not able to decode class file version. see JLS See §4.4 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html

Also you can try running `javap -verbose <class>` on solaris machine.
If it works and return proper output means Solaris jre is able read class file properly.

If not try recompiling java file or try with different java version on solaris.